# Ansible hash password not working

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a variable with `ansible_ssh_user` and `ansible_ssh_pass` in my playbook global variable.  I tried hashing my password with various method but I still couldn't ssh to my remote VMs.  I have tried `ansible_user` and `ansible_pass` but still no luck.  The following are methods I used and it all failed.  I'm not sure what I am missing and hopefully some experts could help.  When I use `clear password`, it works, but not hash.  Here are the methods I've tried but still unsuccessful:-

```
1.  mkpasswd --method=SHA-512
2.  python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; 
    print sha512_crypt.encrypt('<password>')"
3.  # python
    >>> import crypt
    >>> crypt.crypt('<PASSWORD>', '$6$salt$')
4.   cat /etc/shadow | grep <user>
     Try to get the encrypted password but still not working
```

I have confirm my VM is using `ENCRYPTED_METHOD SHA512`.  Nothing is working, appreciate if someone could help

Comment: It could be beneficial to state what you are actually trying to do. Saying just what you did does not explain anything.

Comment: I am trying to run Ansible from machine A, and expect Ansible to ssh to machine B using `ansible_ssh_user` and `ansible_ssh_pass` to perform some tasks.  When `ansible_ssh_pass` is in clear, everything works, i can login via Ansible from machine A to machine B.  The moment I hash the password, it doesn't work.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried hashing my password with various method but I still couldn't ssh to my remote VMs

And for a good reason — to connect to a remote machine with an SSH protocol with password authentication you must provide a **password**, not a password hash.

---

In password authentication users provide passwords and systems process them. As one of security measures, systems store password hashes instead of passwords, so that in case of a breach, the passwords themselves do not get compromised.

If for some reason a system would allow authenticating users using a hash rather then password, it would be a huge security flaw (equal to storing passwords in clear).

If you really need to use password authentication, then Ansible Vault provides a way to protect the passwords. Otherwise use a public key authentication.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if this is documented anywhere in Ansible documentation ?  I will look at `ansible-vault` to encrypt the variable files or Hashicorp vault to store the secrets

Comment: @jlim It’s not documented, because there is really nothing to be documented, especially on Ansible side. In password authentication users provide passwords and systems process these passwords. To provide security, systems store password hashes, so that in case of a breach, the passwords do not get compromised. If for some reason a system would allow authenticating users using a hash rather then password, it would be a huge security flaw. Ansible is not relevant here. Ansible Vault is of course a good way to protect the secrets.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  Can't agree more.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want access your VMs and do something using Ansible.

1. Best practice to use Ansible, is to first setup a public-private key pair.
    https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2
2. Check whether SSH using key-pair is working fine. If it is, you can go ahead.
3. Now suppose if you want to access a host having IP 10.192.34.74. Add the following line to your inventory file:

   10.192.34.72 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/private/key/file

Now it should work.

Comment: The link is not working.  Nevertheless, I could be wrong, this method requires me to copy the public key to every machines that I need to connect, am I right ?  Assuming i'm running ansible in `machine A` and will be executing some tasks into 30 machines.  I need to copy `machine A` public key to all 30 machines for the key pairs to work.  Vice versa, if I'm wrong, I will still need to generate private key in all 30 machines using `ssh-keygen`.  I still need some sort of ways to login into the 30 machines.

Comment: Sorry for incorrect link, i have updated the same. Yes, you're right, you need to copy the public key to all Remote Machines. I am assuming that you're using a central Machine(DOCM) to run Ansible on remote machines. Copying the key is one time task. You can automate it easily using a "for" loop.e.g. "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145182/copy-ssh-public-key-to-multiple-linux-hosts"

Comment: Thanks.  I have experience `ssh-copy-id` before that it requires authentication to copy the key.  That is the reason why I try to avoid using ssh key in ansible but just using plain old user/password credential.  Anyway, I have decided to use clear password `ansible_ssh_pass` in my variable file but secure it with ansible-vault to encrypt the file and store the ansible-vault password in Hashicorp Vault.  This will work but i need to include more tools and effort which I'm trying to avoid in the beginning for a simple setup

Comment: I think @techraf  suggestion for Ansible Vault, should be helpful for your case.